# angularjs ui router regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to match 1 paramater that can have 2 kinds of values: 'current' or a number with at least 10 cyphers.

I've tried:

```
    url: '/history/{code:^current$|^[0-9]{10,}$}'
```

When I use this regexp I get my app to go to `history/current`, but when I reload the page it goes back to the *default*.

Can anyone help by saying what am I doing wrong or how could I debug that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7o3yLMgtFn47bAsbmxiP?p=preview). The state definition is:

```
.state('history', { 
    //url: '/history/{code:^current$|^[0-9]{10,}$}',
    url: "/history/{code:current|[0-9]{10,}}",
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
})
```

And these links should do what we expect:

```
Working:
<a href="#/history/current">history/current</a>
<a href="#/history/0123456789">history/0123456789</a>
<a href="#/history/1234567890123">history/1234567890123</a>

Will FAIL and fall to default:
<a href="#/history/other">history/other</a>
<a href="#/history/012345678">history/012345678</a> - 9 digits
<a href="#/history/123456789a">history/123456789a</a> - a at the end
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7o3yLMgtFn47bAsbmxiP?p=preview)

Comment: Would say, that in this case, we do not have to use them... they are redundant, because the rest of the regex is saying the same...