# angular routes are confused to each other

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello i have two separate routes in angular, like so:

```
    .state('reports1', {
    url: '/reports/user/:userId',
    controller: 'Mycontroller',
    templateUrl: '...html',
    data: {
       ...
    },
})
.state('reports2', {
    url: '/reports/:userId',
    controller: 'Mycontroller',
    templateUrl: '...html',
    data: {
        ...
    },
})
```

The issue is when i type `http://..reports/user` , which should lead to `no page found` , it goes to the `http://..reports/:userId` , because it takes the `user` as the Id param.

Is there a way to distinguish these two urls ?

Answer (score 0):

See this topic

[angularjs ui router regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326108/angularjs-ui-router-regex)

the solution could be to use a regular expression for filtering a suitable prameter (esclude "user" as a :userId parameter value). IN your case you need a different regular expression